# Laravel 5 composer problems

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I try to run this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my-new-app dev-develop
```

And i get this error:

```
 [RuntimeException]
 Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentExceptio
 n' with message 'Dotenv: Environment file .env not found. Create file with
 your environment settings at C:\wamp\www\my-new-app\bootstrap/../.env' in C
 :\wamp\www\my-new-app\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Dotenv.php:20
 Stack trace:
 #0 C:\wamp\www\my-new-app\bootstrap\environment.php(16): Dotenv::load('C:\w
 amp\www\my-...')

 #1 C:\wamp\www\my-new-app\bootstrap\start.php(27): require('C:\wamp\www\my-
 ...')

 #2 C:\wamp\www\my-new-app\artisan(30): require_once('C:\wamp\www\my-...')

 #3 {main}
   thrown in C:\wamp\www\my-new-app\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Dotenv.php o
 n line 20
```

Am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Via Composer Create Project

composer create-project laravel/laravel you_blog "5.1.*"

or you can visit to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add --prefer-dist:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my-new-app dev-develop --prefer-dist
```

Comment: I tried this also but i get the same error..it's not working.

Comment: you're right, i'm sorry. i tried it and got the same error. i also had a co-worker try it and he suffered from the same result (and he uses homestead). i see on the github page for laravel that taylor otwell has updated some of the related files to this error. perhaps it is a new issue :(

Comment: @paulalexandru i can't comment on the other answer but if you want to rename .env.example to .env you can open up that file in a text editor and save as '.env' and set save as type 'all files' since right click>rename to '.env' throws an error. i was able to get the project working after doing that.

Comment: First of all i should run the command and only after that i can rename the file. But when i run the command i get an error, so i get the error before i can rename the file, and my question was : why i get that error, because in the tutorial he don't get any error.

Comment: i cant say why there is an error other than Otwell has made changes to the l5 framework in the past 1-2 days. but i do know that if you run the create laravel project command, then change the env file name despite the error and then run php artisan serve it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a file called .env.example , rename that file to .env and do a composer update.

BTW: You're downloading Laravel 5 (still Alpha)

Comment: Well, that file is inside the project, and i get an error while creating the project. Anyways, i can't rename that file to .env because i get an error. BTW, i am working using this tutorial : https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/2

Comment: It should be `mv .env.example .env` to rename the file